# What's the difference between "include_examples" and "it_behaves_like"?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In RSpec, what's the difference between `it_behaves_like` and `include_examples`?

The [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) says:

> `include_examples` — include(s) the examples in the current context
>
> `it_behaves_like "name"` — include(s) the examples in a nested context

But what does this actually mean? Replacing one with the other doesn't seem to have an effect on whether my tests pass or fail. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other in some situations?

Also, are `it_should_behave_like` and `it_behaves_like` just synonyms?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You probably know how to use `describe`, `context`, `it` and `specify` to clearly communicate one aspect of your code. The nested context provided by `it_behaves_like` can be used to improve this communication with the reader.

I will base my example on the example given in the RSpec documentation for [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

```
shared_examples "a collection" do
  context "initialized with 3 items" do
    it "says it has three items" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end

describe Array do
  it_behaves_like "a collection"
  include_examples "a collection"
end
```

If you run RSpec with `--format documentation` you get the following output:

```
Array
  behaves like a collection
    initialized with 3 items
      says it has three items
  initialized with 3 items
    says it has three items
```

So the difference is how the spec is read eg in case of a failure.

Which style you prefer is a question of aesthetics of how you like your specs to read. Furthermore you would suggest to always use the same style if you work in a team to improve consistency.

---

> Also, are it_should_behave_like and it_behaves_like just synonyms?

Almost, the context is named differently. `it should behave like ...` vs `behaves like ...`. Again a question of aesthetics.

Comment: So to clarify: which of three I use has no effect on whether a test will pass/fail, it's just a choice of aesthetics/readability?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo exactly :)

Answer (score 38):

There **is** a difference in case you pass parameters to the shared_examples.

It's explained very well in a warning [in their doc](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

> WARNING: When you include parameterized examples in the current context multiple
>   times, you may override previous method definitions and last declaration wins.
>   So if you have this kind of shared example (or shared context)

```
RSpec.shared_examples "some example" do |parameter|
  \# Same behavior is triggered also with either `def something; 'some value'; end`
  \# or `define_method(:something) { 'some value' }`
  let(:something) { parameter }
  it "uses the given parameter" do
    expect(something).to eq(parameter)
  end
end

RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  include_examples "some example", "parameter1"
  include_examples "some example", "parameter2"
end
```

> You're actually doing this (notice that first example will fail):

```
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  \# Reordered code for better understanding of what is happening
  let(:something) { "parameter1" }
  let(:something) { "parameter2" }

  it "uses the given parameter" do
    \# This example will fail because last let "wins"
    expect(something).to eq("parameter1")
  end

  it "uses the given parameter" do
    expect(something).to eq("parameter2")
  end
end
```

> To prevent this kind of subtle error a warning is emitted if you
>   declare multiple methods with the same name in the same context.
>   Should you get this warning the simplest solution is to replace
>   include_examples with it_behaves_like, in this way method overriding
>   is avoided because of the nested context created by it_behaves_like

Comment: Also note that the same effect is observed if you add some let variables in a block given to the `include_examples` method : in `include_examples('My shared examples) { let(:variable_only_for_shared_example) { something }` the `let(:variable_only_for_shared_example)` will be overwritten if you have previously defined it.
This can become a pitfall if your rspec shared examples are meant to reuse let variables and you "thought" defining them in a block would do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a big difference between `it_behaves_like` and `include_context` when using the `shared_examples` method.

When you use `include_context` you can inside your `shared_examples` block define `let`, `before`, and `it` statements.  I think probably you can use `context` and `describe` block as well.

But I you use `it_behaves_like`, you can use `it` statements on your shared examples, but if you define some `let` blocks on your `shared_example` they can not be used inside the original `rspec.describe` block that has the `it_behaves_like` statement.

and I think that is a huge difference.

Same applies for `include_examples`. I think probably `include_examples` and `include_context` are very similar.