# Practical way to test controller authentication with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm wondering if there are better ways to write controller request specs than how I currently do it. I'm using the devise gem for authentication. This is how I'd test an admin controller:

```
  describe "#index" do
    context "when not logged in" do
      it "redirects to root page" do
        get admin_index_path

        expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

    context "when logged in as an user" do
      before { sign_in user }

      it "redirects to root page" do
        get admin_index_path

        expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

    context "when logged in as an admin" do
      before { sign_in admin }

      it "opens the page" do
        get admin_index_path
        expect(response).to be_success
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see there is some "boilerplate" code which repeats over many of my controllers. For controllers which require a user to be logged in, I'd had to write a "not logged in" spec for every controller action. How do you do this? Is there a way to maybe shorten/share the code between the specs? The only thing that changes is the path.

Comment: Replace `it_behaves_like` with `include_examples`

Comment: Why one over other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556296/whats-the-difference-between-include-examples-and-it-behaves-like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Linus here is refactored version of your answer

```
shared_examples "requires login" do |path, user_type|
  context "when not logged in" do
    it "redirects to root path" do
      get public_send("#{path}_path")

      expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  context "as an #{user_type}" do
    it "redirects to root path" do
      sign_in create(user_type)

      get public_send("#{path}_path")

      expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

And use it like

`it_behaves_like "requires login", "admin_index", :user` for user

`it_behaves_like "requires login", "admin_index", :admin` for admin

Comment: Nice idea to pass the the user type as a symbol, which is just like factory bot needs it. Thanks!

Comment: How would you pass a path with an object? Example: `edit_course_path(course)`

Comment: `edit_course_path(course)` returns string which you can pass as argument like `it_behaves_like "requires login", edit_course_path(course), :admin`

Comment: But I can only write `edit_course_path(course)` in `it` blocks, right?

Comment: I didn't quite get you @Linus. Can you please add more details?

Comment: Sorry I meant "outside of it blocks". As `it_behaves_like` isn't written inside of `it` blocks, but only inside `describe`/`context` blocks, it throws an error, as path evaluations, like `edit_course_path(course)`, is only available inside of `it` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with this solution. Please let me know if you have any better ideas.

```
shared_examples "requires user login" do |path|
  context "when not logged in" do
    it "redirects to root path" do
      get public_send(path)

      expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  context "as an user" do
    it "redirects to root path" do
      sign_in create(:user)

      get public_send(path)

      expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end

shared_examples "requires admin login" do |path|
  context "as an user" do
    it "redirects to root path" do
      sign_in create(:user)

      get public_send(path)

      expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  context "as an admin" do
    it "gets 200" do
      sign_in create(:admin)

      get public_send(path)

      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

To use them:

```
it_behaves_like "requires user login", "admin_index_path"
```

or

```
it_behaves_like "requires admin login", "admin_index_path"
```